# Best way to display data via JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

i am trying to find the best way to display results on my page via an Ajax call using jQuery, do you think the best way is to pass it as JSON or plain text? I have worked with ajax calls before, but not sure which is preferred over the other and for the JSON version what is the best way to read from a JSON file generated by a PHP page to display my results.

i know I would include a `.each` to run through it to display them all.

Comment: Coughlin/Ryan, edit your question to reflect the discussion below. The answer section is not designed for discussion (rather use the comments for that purpose or update your question with additional details).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://mywebsite.com/json/get.php?cid=15",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.products, function(i,product){
            content = '<p>' + product.product_title + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' + product.product_short_description + '</p>';
            content += '<img src="' + product.product_thumbnail_src + '"/>';
            content += '<br/>';
            $(content).appendTo("#product_list");
          });
        });
```

Would take a json object made from a PHP array returned with the key of products. e.g:

```
Array('products' => Array(0 => Array('product_title' => 'Product 1',
                                     'product_short_description' => 'Product 1 is a useful product',
                                     'product_thumbnail_src' => '/images/15/1.jpg'
                                    )
                          1 => Array('product_title' => 'Product 2',
                                     'product_short_description' => 'Product 2 is a not so useful product',
                                     'product_thumbnail_src' => '/images/15/2.jpg'
                                    )
                         )
     )
```

To reload the list you would simply do:

```
$("#product_list").empty();
```

And then call getJSON again with new parameters.

Comment: For performance reason that $(content).appendTo("#product_list") should be outside of the loop. Appending to DOM is slow and should be done only once.

Comment: Yes that's how it should be, and the first line should be content += if that's going to be the case. However appending to the DOM is quicker in some browsers than others :)

Answer (score 11):

JQuery has an inbuilt json data type for Ajax and converts the data into a object. PHP% also has inbuilt json_encode function which converts an array into json formatted string. Saves a lot of parsing, decoding effort.

Answer (score 4):

Perfect! Thank you Jay, below is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Facebook like ajax post - jQuery - ryancoughlin.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<link href="../css/highlight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("readJSON.php",function(data){
        $.each(data.post, function(i,post){
            content += '<p>' + post.post_author + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' + post.post_content + '</p>';
            content += '<p' + post.date + '</p>';
            content += '<br/>';
            $(content).appendTo("#posts");
        });
    });   
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="span-24">
                       <h2>Check out the following posts:</h2>
                        <div id="posts">
                        </di>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JSON outputs:

```
{ posts: [{"id":"1","date_added":"0001-02-22 00:00:00","post_content":"This is a post","author":"Ryan Coughlin"}]}
```

I get this error, when I run my code:

```
object is undefined
http://localhost:8888/rks/post/js/jquery.js
Line 19
```

Comment: I got it, i changed:

  $.each(data.posts, function(i,post){

So data.post -> data.posts

Answer (score 3):

You can create a jQuery object from a JSON object:

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function(json) {
    $(json).each(function() {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    });
});
```