# read json and put content to div

Tags: jquery, json

i need to read from json like this:

```
{"error_message":"Only post requests are allowed","reservations":null,"error_code":1}
```

and put the results into 3 different div. I'm watching this code [Best way to display data via JSON using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327231/best-way-to-display-data-via-json-using-jquery) changing the json link and linking the external resource of jquery but i can't find where is the problem. thanks

here is my actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("./reservations.json",function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,post){
            content += '<h3>' + error_message + '</h3>';
            $(content).appendTo("#error_message");
        });
    });  
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="error_message"></div>
        <div id="reservations"></div>
        <div id="error_code"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try posting your code so we can help you better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content += '<h3>' + error_message + '</h3>';
```

Neither `content` nor `error_message` is defined anywhere, so this line won't work.

Try using:

```
var content = '<h3>' + post.error_message + '</h3>';
```

Also, if the JSON is exactly like shown in the question, you don't need `$.each`.

```
var content = '<h3>' + data.error_message + '</h3>';
$(content).appendTo("#error_message");
```

Comment: Actually error_message isn't defined anywhere either.. using data.error_message in your original code should work simone

Comment: @Mvision: Thanks.  I realized this too right after typing this.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your JSON is stored in a variable:

```
var json = {"error_message":"Only post requests are allowed","reservations":null,"error_code":1};
```

Let's say your 3 `div`s are

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

If you wanted to place the error message into each of those `div`s:

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3').text(json.error_message);
```

Comment: I think you can help on my json related question. I have to retrive json value from two json file and append to two divs(test.txt to div1 and test2.txt to div2), How can i do that? I am struggling on my code for 2 days. here is the question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260370/