# Retrieving JSON data from an external file using jQuery Ajax not working in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: json, jquery, cross-browser

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from an external text file using a `GET` request. The code is workinh in Firefox, but it's not working in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

The JavaScript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/test.txt",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            //alert("Success");
            $.each(data.dashboard, function(i,post){
                 $('#slider ul').append('<li><a href="'+post.TargetUrl+'" target="'+post.Target+'"><img src="' + post.ImageUrl + '" title="' + post.OverlayText +'" /></a></li>');
            });
            handleSuccess();
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    });
});
```

JSON data on a text file

```
{
    dashboard: [
    {
        "ImageUrl": "images/01.jpg",
        "OverlayText": "demo image 1",
        "TargetUrl": "http://lkamal.com.np",
        "Target": "_blank",
        "Timer ": 2000
    },
    {
        "ImageUrl": "images/02.jpg",
        "OverlayText": "demo image 2",
        "TargetUrl": "http://lkamal.com.np",
        "Target": "_blank",
        "Timer ": 2000
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you inspect the final URL and the actual error you're getting in the Chrome inspector or IE developer tools?

Comment: chrome inspector says:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/projects/r3dImage/ajax/test.txt?_=1307137974704. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript generally isn't allowed to load files from the file system. You'd have to host the project on a web server, then the URL would work, like `http://localhost/ajax/test.txt` if you host your project on `http://localhost/`.

Comment: now I have to retrive data from multiple json file and show them in respective div( one div for one datafile). can you help me on that?

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/json-jquery-ajax-php.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539604/read-json-and-put-content-to-div might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for the problem on chrome is when you access your script localy you would have to give the full path as url. so instead of emaple/test.txt you should give D://username/file/test.txt(make sure you use forward slashes).