# jquery update database

Tags: php, jquery, function

Very new to jquery here, as evident by this question:

I want to execute some php code if a jquery function is run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function this() {
      if(this == that) {
      // echo "done"; update database
      }
  }
</script>
```

How would I run php in the line that's commented. Or what do I have to do instead.

Comment: search for ajax, jquery POST or GET...

Comment: You can't run PHP from within javascript, but you can do an AJAX request to a PHP script. That has been already asked and that often that I'm too lazy to look-up any of the duplicates and close-vote right ahead.

Comment: Use either get or post.. as already mentioned by @achusonline to send the request to your server to do it.

Comment: call function name `this` isn't wise... =)

Comment: -5? this is a help site correct?

Comment: Not one of the downvoters, but you are probably getting them because your question looks like you're asking for a lot of code, and the code you've presented wouldn't actually work. Most people want to see that you've put in some effort to solve it yourself, and then that's where this site steps in.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because javascript runs in the browser and php runs on the server. In other words, doing a test from javascript cannot execute php because the page has already left the server.

But here is what you can do. But the php in its own page and activate it on the server with jQuery ajax like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function this() {
        if(this == that) {
           $.post('#url to your php file', function(){ 
               //do something in javascript AFTER the php file has run.
          });
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Ajax. There is the basic load() function if you don't need to pass any variables to the PHP, or there are more advanced methods.

Here is a basic tutorial, although if you do a search you will likely find better ones.
http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You would not run PHP within JavaScript. The typical approach is to use an AJAX request to send the query to a PHP page on the server.

Refer to this:
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327231/best-way-to-display-data-via-json-using-jquery/327640#327640)

Feel free to ask if you don't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function this() {
      if(this == that) {
          $.getScript('phpfile.php?'.$.serialize(params));
      }
  }
</script>
```

There are several other approaches. You really should have done some research, as there are lots of available references to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit it via AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function this() {
      if(this == that) {
             $.post("update.php");
      }
  }
</script>
```