# How can I display Data from mysql using json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can I display data from the database using json php and mysql .
I have been trying but I am failing to win but if I don’t include jquery it displays but in a funny way .
I will appreciate for any help .
Bellow is what I have tried so far.

```
<?php 
require_once('dbbox.php');
?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 
m1debtors INNER JOIN 
m1dtrans 
ON m1debtors.name = m1dtrans.user";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$accnum =  $row['accnum'];
$name = $row['name'];
$addr1 = $row['addr1'];
}
// The JSON standard MIME header.
header('Content-type: application/json');
$array = array('Name'=>$name, 'user'=>$user);
 echo  json_encode($array);
?>
Here is the html page to display data 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("view.php",{$name});
});
</script>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try these link http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/json-jquery-ajax-php.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327231/best-way-to-display-data-via-json-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

**view.php**

```
<?php 
  require_once('dbbox.php');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM m1debtors 
          INNER JOIN m1dtrans 
            ON m1debtors.name = m1dtrans.user";
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $accnum =  $row['accnum'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $addr1 = $row['addr1'];
  }

  // The JSON standard MIME header.
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $array = array('name'=>$name, 'user'=>$user);
   echo  json_encode($array);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('view.php', function(data) {
          $('#myJson').html(data.name + ' ' + data.user);
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myJson"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('view.php',function(data){
console.log(data.name +' '+ data.user);
});
});
</script>

Comment: thats what exactly I did but am using the sampe page where the php codes are is that a problem ?

Comment: Yes it is a problem.. You should put js code and your php output in separate files

Comment: yes I separated the codes but still it displays nothing bt no errors

Comment: I really cant understand I did exactly wat u said and even I copy that code u drooped bt still no display